# Modify Upload.aspx for a Document Library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, list, document-library

I need to modify the `upload.aspx` for a document library.

I have a requirement where for example I have following fields:
1) Title
2) category(lookup)
3) Body( Rich Text Field)
4) File(document field)

I need to modify the `upload.aspx` such that I can include these fields on the form.

I mean when I click on new document, the above fields should appear along with Add file.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to modify the SharePoint file. Just create a new Content type, attach each field to it, attach it to the library, set it as the default on the library, then they will show up after you upload your file.

Comment: Or no need to create the content type, just add the fields in Library Settings -> Columns..

Comment: The file field is not mandatory, so i have to modify the upload.aspx page.

Comment: That is for the next page that appears after i click new document.
I need to add fields to upload.aspx
I am not sure if i can do it.

Comment: Your question doesn't explain any of that. What's a document field? Why does a non required field mean you have to modify upload.aspx?

Comment: In brief,
When i click on new document in a library, i need a sort of list item form to appear (like newform.aspx) with fields title, category and file. But in a document library that form will only appear after i upload a file, but i need that form to appear before i add the file. So i have to make my upload.aspx into a newform.aspx
I hope i made it clear now